# Newtonsoft unable to deserialize datetime in a certain format

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
string json= "{\"DATA_UPDATE_CHECK\":[{\"BOY\":{\"BIRTH_DATE\":\"2015-06-29T00:00:00\",\"DEATH_DATE\":\"1982-09-01T00:00:00\"},\"GIRL\":null,\"ID\":\"0105320\"}]}";

var jsonoutput = JObject.Parse(json);

var x =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataLastUpdate>>(jsonoutput["DATA_UPDATE_CHECK"].ToString());
```

I want to read the above json as a List of custom class below.

```
public class DataLastUpdate
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public DataLastUpdateType BOY{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public DataLastUpdateType GIRL{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string ID { get; set; }

}

public class DataLastUpdateType
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public DateTime BIRTH_DATE{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public DateTime DEATH_DATE{ get; set; }

}
```

When I run the code , instead of the date times in the JSON , my result list has the date time fields  as 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  .

My guess is it cannot read the format correctly. Please advise how to add a custom date time converter to enable deserailaztion or if there is a simpler way ?!

Comment: The JSON you've provided doesn't seem to correspond at all with the classes you've given. Please provide a meaningful [mcve].

Comment: your classes in no way match the JSON you are trying to deserialize?  for example - which property should `BIRTH_DATE` map to in `DataLastUpdate` or `DataLastUpdateType`?  On a side note the value you are getting for the dates is the default zero value of a non-initialized `DateTime` object, hence why it has a value at all

Comment: sorry.. forgot to edit the class while editing the json. pls check now

Comment: @JakeSlattery I just copied and pasted your code into a new console project and ran it - the deserialization appears to work just fine as you have it right now.  Are you sure that you don't have some kind of typo on your side?

Comment: you are right !!  :( sorry